# issue with 'addClass' in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    a.red {
        color: red;
    }
    a.green {
        color: green;
    }   
    a.yellow {
        color: yellow;
    }   
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[href^=red]').addClass('red');
        $('a[href$=.jpg]').addClass('green');
        $('a[href*=pic]').addClass('yellow');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="red.gif">red</a></br>
<a href="green.jpg">green</a></br>
<a href="yellowpic.png">yellow</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Question:

In the front-end, only red color works, green and yellow color does not work, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs

```
jQuery( "[attribute='value']" )
```

**attribute**: An attribute name.

**value**: An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string.

You have to add `"` around the matched string.

```
$('a[href^="red"]').addClass('red');
$('a[href$=".jpg"]').addClass('green');
$('a[href*="pic"]').addClass('yellow');
           ^   ^
```

So it'll work for more than one word, like

```
$('a[value*="some value"]')
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ADBn3/1/)

Comment: ok dot is understandable with quotes but why do we need double quotes around pic, why it doesn't work similar like the red ?

Comment: @AnmolSaraf It works, if you remove `"` from pic it'll match the element. http://jsfiddle.net/ADBn3/2/

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape `.` with `\\.` as it is a reserved character in jquery selectors or just wrap the attribute value in quotes.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         $('a[href^=red]').addClass('red');
         $('a[href$=\\.jpg]').addClass('green'); // < --Here 
         //$('a[href$="jpg"]').addClass('green');
         $('a[href*=pic]').addClass('yellow');
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gV7pA/)**

Issue is that you get a syntax error in the second line and your third line never executes as the script breaks.

*From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)*

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \.

Comment: Oh, "I will always open console even if the code looks ok", "I will always open console even if the code looks ok", "I will always open console even if the code looks ok", "I will always open console even if the code looks ok", "I will always open console even if the code looks ok", "I will always open console even if the code looks ok", "I will always open console even if the code looks ok", "I will always open console even if the code looks ok", "I will always open console even if the code looks ok", "I will always open console even if the code looks ok"

Comment: or you don't put ".", just have `$('a[href$=jpg]')`.

Comment: @zerkms this is the syntax error issue in the selector. `To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. `

Comment: @PSL or simply wrapped in `quotes` `°_°`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Agreed, but seriously myjpg.png? I will have quite a few concerns with that naming convention.

Comment: @bazz nooo no no no I commented wrongly. removed. nonsense. not needed whan `$` I was messing with `*` in my thoughts